# Can I create WeakReference to a JavaScript object in Nashorn?

Tags: javascript, java, weak-references, nashorn

I'm trying to have weak references in a JavaScript program that I'm running in Nashorn.  It seems like this should be possible because I can instantiate a Java WeakReference object passing it the JavaScript object.  It appears that this does not work however.

```
// weaknash.js
var WeakRef = Java.type("java.lang.ref.WeakReference");
var obj = {p: "abc"};
var wr = new WeakRef(obj);
print(obj);      // should print object
print(wr.get()); // should print object
Packages.java.lang.System.gc();
print(obj);      // should print object
print(wr.get()); // should print object
obj = null;
Packages.java.lang.System.gc();
print(obj);      // should print null
print(wr.get()); // should print null
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
$ jjs weaknash.js 
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
null
null
null
```

I would expect an output that is the following:

```
$ jjs weaknash.js 
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
null
null
```

The problem is that even though there is still `obj` still contains a reference to the object, the object referenced by `wr` is collected by the garbage collector.  Despite this, the object `obj` is still useable.

What do I do to make `WeakReference` correctly track a JavaScript object in Nashorn?

Comment: What's the purpose to have a WeakReference? Why not just use an object per se?

Comment: My purpose is a caching system where identical objects are forced to be reference identical.  However if all references to a particular object are deleted it should be free to be collected.  The problem is implementing this requires maintaining a cache somewhere that contains a reference to each object. Unless that cache uses weak references, no objects can be ever be collected.